# Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, classification, pytorch

I'm new to neural nets and am trying to train a simple neural net in Pytorch with labeled data as a classifier. The data contains 6 features and 3 labels. Unfortunately, when I run the code, the error code:

> Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.

I've read all possible threads on this topic, and haven't found a solution that solves this problem for me.

My labels are 0, 1, and 2 and my feature data is numerical in the range of ~-12 to ~2000.

Any ideas?

```
#hyperparameters
hl = 10
lr = 0.01
num_epoch = 500

#build model
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(6, hl)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hl, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
net = Net()

#choose optimizer and loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

#train
for epoch in range(num_epoch):
    X = Variable(torch.Tensor(xtrain).float())
    Y = Variable(torch.Tensor(ytrain).long())

    #feedforward - backprop
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = net(X)
    loss = criterion(out, Y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if (epoch) % 50 == 0:
        print ('Epoch [%d/%d] Loss: %.4f' 
                   %(epoch+1, num_epoch, loss.data[0]))
```

Comment: Follow the error. Verify your labels are correct.

Comment: What are `xtrain` and `ytrain`? How are they shaped?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with

```
xtrain = [[ 1.0721,  0.7327, -0.3655,  1.0686, -0.5575,  1.0052],
          [ 0.5194, -0.0946,  0.0181,  0.6665,  0.0231,  0.3278],
          [-0.2119, -0.5824, -0.8057,  0.5669, -1.3236, -0.1913]]
ytrain = [0, 1, 2]
```

buf if I set `ytrain = [0, 1, 3]`, I get your error. I'd say check that your labels indeed contain only 0, 1, and 2.
Could also be that the shape of your data doesn't match that of your layers (see also https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-assertion-cur-target-0-cur-target-n-classes-failed/8034/2).